# Sharepoint Workflow - Due Date

Tags: workflow

I wish to know if the task due date for the pre-built Approval Workflow, can have email reminders once the date is approaching. (Without using Sharepoint Designer) Lets say the DueDate for this approval is tml, can I ask sharepoint to send a reminder email to the task person to remind him to approve this task?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist OOB but you can use Information Policy settings to start a workflow based on a reminder date.

Laura has already done this for you: [Workflow- Reminder Before Due Date – MOSS vs. WSS](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=64).

Post is in SP2007 but should be applicable for SP2013.

Comment: +1 For mentioning Laura a.k.a. godess of SharePoint